# Нужен совет по способу реализации

Tags: android, c#, .net, asp.net, xamarin

Разрабатываю приложение, в котором можно будет найти некоторые обьекты на карте. При этом нужно что бы пользователи могли добавлять эти самые обьекты. Возможно ли реализовать что-то по типу администрирования, чтобы обрабатывать эти запросы? Как вообще происходит этот процесс? Пока что я пришёл к выводу что можно создать определенный контроллер (на asp.net), через который можно будет получать эти обьекты из базы данных, но у меня недостаточно информации. Если это возможно, напишите названия этих технологий чтобы я мог свободно искать в интернете.
Спасибо :)

Comment: Половина существующих веб-технологий подойдут для решения задачи.Определитесь, чего вы конкретно хотите прежде, чем задавать вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал бы так: Приложение работает с базой данных на сервере, где хранятся эти объекты, общается через php. И веб приложение для редактирования, либо что Вам будет удобнее, десктопное к примеру.

Comment: Я именно это и сказал) Скажите как мне "общаться" через asp.net. Это response на request или как? Я не понимаю как сделать запрос конкретно к какому то методу на сервере, который вернет мне коллекцию

Comment: Извиняйте, но в asp.net я не помощник, не работал с данной технологией.

Comment: Технология MVC подойдет для этого?

Comment: Не уверен, вот к примеру первых ссылок на  [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147038/), там пишут что технология MVC устарела.